# iptables rule to accept udp traffic on port

Tags: iptables

I have a VPS box with 4 external ips on it and I need to open the udp port for each ip in part but I can't seem to get it right with ip tables. Here's my rule so far:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d 98.158.xxx.86 -p udp --dport 34121 -j ACCEPT
```

The program I'm using needs to connect to that ip via udp but the server does not allow it. any ideas?

Comment: First, are you sure it's UDP? second, are you sure you don't need a rule in the OUTPUT chain?

Comment: I'm sure it's udp. Second, I'm not sure :)

Comment: Are you sure your application listen on this IP or something like 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: `iptables -I INPUT` requires entry number.

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned off the firewall altogether just to confirm that what you want to do will work?  If it works with out it then at least you know its your rule, if it does not then there is something else going on that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the ip not being the main server ip.

Comment: Are you running anything like SE Linux on the server?  I have run into problems kinda like this when I have used SE Linux in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to limit your destination IP, you can safely drop -d. You do, however, need to match the protocol with "-m". So you need to do this:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m udp -p tcp --deport 32121 -j ACCEPT (for Red Hat / Centos 5)
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -m udp -p tcp --deport 32121 -j ACCEPT (for Red Hat / Centos 6)
```

At any event, if you are still unable to connect, try running a snoop or tcpdump on the interfaces to verify that you have two-way traffic.

Comment: "-m udp" is equivalent to "-p udp". He had it right in the question.